# Python: numpy.linalg.norm produces different result than np.sum(np.abs(x)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, norm

I have 2 images with size (256,256,3) and I want to calculate the norm-2 of their difference.

```
# Original Image

np_ori = np.array(icon_original).reshape(1,-1)

# My reconstructed image

np_0 = np.array(icon_0).reshape(1,-1)
```

If I use numpy.linalg.norm

```
norm_org_0 = np.linalg.norm(np_ori-np_0)
```

I get

```
62735
```

When I use  np.sum(np.abs(x)*2,axis=-1)**(1./2)

```
np.sum(np.abs(np_ori-np_0)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)
```

I get

```
2207
```

The results are the same even if I use `.reshape(-1)` to turn it to vector

Shouldn't those two produce the same result?

Comment: @xjcl With axis = -1 I get array([ 2207.36290628]) ,
Without axis= -1 I get 2207.3629062752684

Comment: Could be datatype issue. Consider converting to float64 and then performing computations.

Comment: @Divakar Now they are the same, thanks ! :)

Comment: Since your problem is solved and its solution is unlikely to help future readers, consider deleting your question.  Since you don't have any votes nor answers on it, you can do this without any repercussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Divakar mentioned is was a datatype issue. Converting to float64 solved the problem.